# SPLIT operator in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to separate reviews_per_month into 2 groups from https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data

```
    NY_Airbnb_data = LOAD 'AB_NYC_2019.csv' using PigStorage (',') as (id:int, name:chararray, host_id:int, host_name:chararray, neighbourhood_group:chararray, neighbourhood:chararray, lattitude:double, longitude:double, room_type:chararray, price:int, minimum_night:int, number_of_review:int, last_review:datetime, reviews_per_month:double, calculated_host_listing_count:int, availability_365:int);

    b0 = FOREACH NY_Airbnb_data GENERATE name, neighbourhood_group, neighbourhood, room_type, reviews_per_month; 
    b1 = SPLIT b0 into b2 if reviews_per_month<1, b3 if (reviews_per_month>1.5);
    dump b2;
```

This is the error I get 
grunt> b1 = SPLIT b0 into b2 if reviews_per_month<1, b3 if (b0.reviews_per_month>1.5);
2019-11-30 01:48:12,232 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'b1'

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `SPLIT` is simply:

```
SPLIT b0 into b2 if reviews_per_month<1, b3 if (reviews_per_month>1.5);
```

No `b1 =` at the start. If you want the records with `reviews_per_month` >= 1 and <= 1.5 to go into `b1`, you have to specify a default relation:

```
SPLIT b0 INTO b2 IF reviews_per_month < 1, b3 IF reviews_per_month > 1.5, b1 OTHERWISE;
```